# How can I skip the first post in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I skip the first post in WordPress?

```
<?php
$recentPosts = new WP_Query();
$recentPosts->query(array('showposts' => 6,'post_type' =>array('stiri')));
?>
<?php while ($recentPosts->have_posts()) : $recentPosts->the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 14):

Use the [`offset`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) parameter:

```
<?php
$recentPosts = new WP_Query( 'offset=1' ) );
$recentPosts->query(array('showposts' => 6,'post_type' =>array('stiri')));
?>
<?php while ($recentPosts->have_posts()) : $recentPosts->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. Setting the offset will break pagination.

Answer (score 2):

Use the **offset**

```
$recentPosts = new WP_Query (
   array(
     'post_type'      => 'stiri',
     'post_status'    => 'publish',
     'posts_per_page' => 6, // all = -1
     'orderby'        => 'date',
     'order'          => 'DESC',
     'offset'         => 1
   )
);
```